# On a certain action of a group $G$ on the image of an injective function $f:G \rightarrow X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, group-actions

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $X$ be a nonempty set. Let $f:G \rightarrow X$ be an injective function with range $\text{Im }f$ and left-inverse $f^{-1}$. Consider the $G$-action on $\text{Im}\; f$ defined by $a\cdot y := f(af^{-1}(y))$, for all $(a,y) \in G \times \text{Im }f$.

Indeed, this is a group-action because

- $e_G\cdot y = f(e_Gf^{-1}(y)) = f(f^{-1}(y)) = y$ forall $y \in \text{Im}\; f$.
- For $a,b \in G$ and $y \in \text{Im }f$, noting that $bf^{-1}(y) = f^{-1}(b\cdot y)$, we have

$$
\begin{split}
(ab)\cdot y &:= f((ab)f^{-1}(y)) = f(a(bf^{-1}(y)))\\
&= f(af^{-1}(b\cdot y)) =: a\cdot(b \cdot y)
\end{split}
$$

Moreover, this action is a *free* group-action since all the stabilizers are trivial, i.e the set $\text{Stab}_G(y) := \{g \in G \mid a\cdot y = y\}$ is the singleton $\{e_G\}$ for all $y \in \text{Im }f$.

### Question

- Have such group actions been studied before ?
- Do they have a canonical name ? Do they have any interesting properties ?
- Are the any interesting things which can been said or asked about such situation (i.e $G$ and $X$ and the above group action) ?

Answer (score 1):

In representation theory,

I think that we can use such actions to define new representations.

When $V$ and $W$ are $k$-linear representations of a group $G$, you can define a representation on $\text{Hom}_{k}(V,W)$ using an action looking like yours and it is also the most naturel way to define an action:
[image]

Comment: Great. Thanks for the nice insight. Any references ?

Comment: I think you can find some discussions in "Linear representations of finite groups" written by Serre. I figured out that when you look at a k-vector space finite-dimensionnal V with a G-action, the action above is precisely the only action on $V^{**}$ such that the canonical isomorphism between V and $V^{**}$ is G-equivariant!

Comment: Great. Thanks. Also, note that my group is not finite, but I get the general point...